# ImportError: no module named guardian

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, django-guardian

I'm new to Django, so generally I am the cause of most of my problems, but I can't figure out why the django-guardian 1.3 app won't install. I'm using Django 1.7 in a virtual environment, my OS is Windows 8.1.

I followed the installation directions at [pythonhosted.org/django-guardian/installation.html](http://pythonhosted.org/django-guardian/installation.html) and configuration at [pythonhosted.org/django-guardian/configuration.html](http://pythonhosted.org/django-guardian/configuration.html), but I get an error when I attempt to run the program.

I added 'guardian', ANONYMOUS_USER_ID, and the backends to my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for VolunteerManager project.
For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/
For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'Super Super Secret'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
ANONYMOUS_USER_ID = -1

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
#DEFAULT APPS
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

#THIRD PARTY APPS
    'guardian',
    'registration',
        #Copyright (c) 2007-2012, James Bennett
        #All rights reserved.
    'django.contrib.sites',

#LOCAL APPS
    'Volunteer',
)

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7 # One-week activation window;
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True # Automatically log the user in.

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', 
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'VolunteerManager.urls'


#ANONYMOUS_USER_ID = 'VOLUNTEER_USER_ID'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'VolunteerManager.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'volunteer',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '$',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/'

SITE_ID = 1
```

[Error picture available on IMGUR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqum6.png)

Django-guardian appears to be installed in my virtual environment, but it's still not finding it. Any ideas what I might have done wrong? (Or other suggestions for per-object permissions in Django?) Thank You!

UPDATE: I narrowed the problem down to the virtualenv. When I installed the modules without using virtualenv, then django finds them like it should. I'm still not sure what exactly I did wrong, but this works for now, considering that I'm only working on one project at the moment.

Comment: What does `python -c 'import guardian'` in the virtualenv yield?

Comment: python -c "import guardian" simply returns the command prompt with no error message, I think that means it's working correctly.

Comment: Yeah, it means that the guardian module is accessible. Is it possible that django believes it should use the site-wide packages instead of the virtualenv packages? Did you install django and initialize the project in the virtualenv, too?

Comment: oh! I initialized the project before installing the virtual environment, then continued working inside it. That must have been the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I narrowed the problem down to the virtualenv. When I installed the
>   modules without using virtualenv, then django finds them like it
>   should.

You need to activate the virtual environment each time your run django, otherwise you'll continue to run into issues like what you have described.

Activating the virtual environment (by executing `Scripts\activate.bat`) sets the correct environment variables to that all Python commands are run against the virtual environment's Python installation.

If you do not run the `activate.bat` file before running Python commands, they will be executed against the system-wide Python installation.

The reason django it works is because you are running django without the virtualenv activated; and you also happen to have django installed in the global Python environment.

Comment: Thank you, that does sound like a reasonable answer, but the virtual environment was indeed activated. You can see in the linked picture that my prompt has changed, and django-guardian was installed inside that virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter the same problem:

The reason might be you don't own the virtualenv folder and all its contents inside, thus

`sudo chown -R /path/to/venv`

should work.